# Product of Power Series of Different Powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to find the product $M$ of two power series of the form

\begin{equation}
M=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\, x^{2n}\right)
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}\, x^{n}\right)
\end{equation}

where, $a_{n}=\frac{(-ag^{2})^{n}}{n!}$, and $b_{n}=\frac{(2ag)^{n}}{n!}$.

The product of the two series could be found with the standard formula (discrete convolution) if both series contained powers of $x^{n}$. I have tried to find a way to calculate the product but am not making progress.  One potential issues is that $a_{n}$ is alternating and would become imaginary if the square root is taken. How can I calculate this product?

P.S- I suspect the final answer will be an infinite sum over confluent hypergeometric functions.

***Additional Information***

I am working on an integral of the form

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} x\, e^{-a(gx-b)^{2}}\, e^{-\mu x}\, {_{1}}F_{1}[-\alpha,-\beta,\lambda x] \ dx
\end{equation}

If I keep my limits of integration and write the exponential as a power series I can solve the integral.  There is no way I can find to solve the integral if I substitute $u=x-b$.  I tried tackling this by writing the exponential in quesiton as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
e^{-a(gx-b)^{2}} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-a)^{n}(gx-b)^{2n}}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-a)^{n}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-b)^{2n-k}(gx)^{k}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Switching the order of summation allows for a solution as a single sum:

\begin{equation}
e^{-a(gx-b)^{2}} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\,
\frac{(-a)^{k/2}(-g)^{k}}{\frac{k}{2}!}\,{_{1}}F_{1}\left(\frac{k+1}{2};\frac{1}{2},-ab^{2}\right)\, x^{k}
\end{equation}

This sum has imaginary terms for odd $k$ and is not particularly useful for my purposes.

Comment: Define $c_n$ by $c_{2n+1}=0$ and $c_{2n}=a_n$. Then $M=(\sum c_n x^n)(\sum b_n x^n)$.

Comment: In this case, two exponential functions?

Comment: @Andre Nicolas Yes this is the product of two exponential functions.  I need the final series to be of the form $\sum c_{n}x^{n}$ because I am integrating the $x^{n}$.

Comment: @Kelenner So are you saying to write $M =\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{2n}\,x^{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}\, x^{n}\right)$

Comment: It might be more natural to express as a single exponential and complete the square.

Comment: @Aaron Hendricksson: No; with the $c_n$ I have defined, if $M=\sum d_n x^n$, you have $d_n=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k b_{n-k}=\sum_{2|k , 0\leq k\leq n}c_{k}b_{n-k}=\sum_{2|k , 0\leq k\leq n}a_{k/2}b_{n-k}$ But with your functions the remark of André is perhaps better: you have $M(x)=\exp(-ag^2x^2+2agx)$.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas This is a long story I will make it short. I am working on an integral with bounds from zero to infinity that contains an exponential of the form $e^{-a(gx-b)^{2}}$ along with a polynomial and confluent hypergeometric function.  Problem is that if I try to sub $u=x-b$, I lose my lower bound of zero leaving me with an integral that has no closed form.  I am trying to get rid of the $(x-b)$ in the exponential so I expanded the argument of the exponential and brought the $e^{-ab^{2}}$ constant leaving me with $e^{-a(g^{2}x^{2}-2bgx)}$ which I need to write as a power series in $x$.

Comment: @Kelenner  if I write $d_{n}$ as you propose, I get an imaginary component.  Was looking for a way to avoid that.  I will post an update in questio explaining one approach I took.

Comment: If you use that $M^{\prime}(x)=(-2ag^2x+2ag)M(x)$, you get that $$ (m+1)d_{m+1}=-2ag^2d_{m-1}+2agd_m$$ But I do not know if this is useful for you.

Comment: I have not understand "imaginary component"

Comment: @Kelenner I tried that approach but the recurrence relation is a nightmare to solve.  Although I suspect the solution to the recurrence is a confluent hypergeometric function.  The imaginary bit come from the fact that $a_{k}=\frac{(-a*g^{2})^{k}}{k!}$ where $a>0$ so $a_{k/2}$ is imaginary.

Comment: The $a_{k/2}$ are here when $k$ is even. Rewrite completely the formula to see that $$d_n=\sum a_l b_{n-2l}$$ where we sum over the $l$ such that $0\leq 2l\leq n$

Comment: @Kelenner Is there a way to find a solution to $d_{n}$ such that I have a single power series over $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the standard formula with a slight variation:

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{2k}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_lx^l\right)
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{2k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}a_kb_l\right)x^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}a_kb_{n-2k}\right)x^n\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) the condition for the inner sum is $2k+l=n$ to respect the even powers $x^{2k}$ and all powers $x^l$.
- In (2) we use the *[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* to set the upper limit of the inner sum and use $l=n-2k$.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested:  Using the answer posted by @Markus Scheuer, I found a series representation for the exponential function in the additional information part of the question I posted.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
e^{-a(gx-b)^{2}} &= e^{-ag^{2}x^{2}}e^{2abgx}e^{-ab^{2}}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-ag^{2})^{n}}{n!}x^{2n}\right)
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2abg^{2})^{n}}{n!}x^{n}\right)e^{-ab^{2}}\\
&=e^{-ab^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{(-ag^{2})^{k}}{k!}\frac{(2abg)^{n-2k}}{(n-2k)!}\right)\, x^{n}\\
&=e^{-ab^{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}U\left(-\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2},ab^{2}\right)\, \frac{(2\sqrt{a}g)^{n}}{n!}\, x^{n}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where, $U(a,b,z)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind (a.k.a. Kummer U function).

Thanks for all your help.